# How to create shard&index in airflow mongohook?

Tags: airflow

I want to run mongo command with mongohook of airflow. How can I do it?

```
sh.shardCollection(db_name +, { _id: "hashed" }, false, { numInitialChunks: 128 });
db.collection.createIndex({ "field": 1 }, { field: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`pymongo` client](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which the `Mongohook` provided in Airflow uses doesn't support the `sh.shardCollection` command in your script.

Though the [`createIndex`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=createindex#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index) collection method is supported in the `pymongo` client.

I recommend anyway to install the [mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/) CLI binary and bake it into your container image for your workers.

You can write your shell command to a script such as `/dags/templates/mongo-admin-create-index.js` or some other location that it can be found.

Then can implement a custom operator using the `SubprocessHook` to run mongosh CLI command such as:

`mongosh -f {mongosh_script} {db_address}`

This custom operator would be along these lines

```py
from airflow.compat.functools import cached_property
from airflow.hooks.subprocess import SubprocessHook
from airflow.providers.mongo.hooks import MongoHook

class MongoshScriptOperator(BaseOperator):

    template_fields: Sequence[str] = ('mongosh_script')

    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        mongosh_script: str,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mongosh_script = mongosh_script

    @cached_property
    def subprocess_hook(self):
        """Returns hook for running the shell command"""
        return SubprocessHook()

    def execute(self):
        """Executes a mongosh script"""
        mh = MongoHook(self.conn_id)
        
        self.subprocess_hook.run_command(
            command=['mongosh', '-f', self.mongosh_script, mh.uri],
        )
```

When creating the `DagNode`, you can pass the location of the script to your custom operator.